# Running a Ruby interpreter on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, ruby, ipad

I'll be taking a trip soon with my iPad, without my laptop.  I'd like to continue to tinker with Ruby while I'm on the road.  I have an iPhone developer program membership, and I'm *not* interested in submitting this stuff to the app store.

I found the [shinycocos](http://github.com/funkaster/shinycocos) project, which appears to embed a Ruby interpreter in an app.  But I can't get it to run, and it seems pretty customized for running cocos2d stuff.

My first goal is to run an interactive command line like [Try Ruby!](http://tryruby.org).  After that, I'd like to enter small programs in a UITextView and run them.  I'd appreciate any clues, tips, or existing projects you might know of.

Comment: Now we have [Pythonista](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/) for Python and [Codea](http://twolivesleft.com/Codea/) for Lua. I'm still looking for the smooth solution for running a Ruby interpreter on iPad.

Comment: Not a current solution but a project to watch, WebKit with Ruby built in: http://trydecaf.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm now using [mruby-web-irb](https://github.com/xxuejie/mruby-web-irb), which meets the requirements stated.

The project provides a Ruby interpreter in Safari (or Chrome) by compiling [mruby](https://github.com/mruby/mruby) into Javascript via [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten). That sounds like a lot of complexity, but it *just works*.

If you like this kind of thing, definitely check out the [emscripten demos](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki). Especially [repl.it](http://repl.it/), an *Online REPL for 15+ languages*, including Ruby, Python, Lua, Scheme, Forth, and Basic.

Answer (score 6):

The [Rhodes Framework](http://RhoMobile.Com/products/rhodes/) contains a working Ruby implementation for the iPhone. You could try just writing your own simple IRB clone with Rhodes and see how that goes. You won't be able to get it through the App Store, of course, but you don't care about that, anyway.

As a next step, you could steal [their build recipes](https://GitHub.Com/Rhomobile/Rhodes/tree/master/platform/iphone/) and compile your own.

In the future, it will probably be possible to use [MacRuby](http://MacRuby.Org/), but for the time being, everybody who works on MacRuby either works for Apple or has signed an NDA, so they aren't saying anything. However, the MacRuby lead developer once said that MacRuby's ahead-of-time compiler *could* in the future be used to "run Ruby on resource-constrained small-size mobile internet devices" without ever mentioning the i-word.

[Note that this will probably *not* allow you to run an interpreter on the device, rather you would statically compile your code natively and then upload it to the device. And the compiler does not support `eval`, which is crucial for running something like IRB or even a full IDE on the device.]

At the moment, your best bet for a mobile Ruby IDE is probably Android.

Comment: "At the moment, your best bet for a mobile Ruby IDE is probably Android."

Answer (score 6):

There is an iPhone project which embeds a Ruby interpreter and provides a basic command line at https://github.com/takuma104/iphone-irb. I compiled it and could install in on an iPad without problems. Unfortunately the project seems to be abandoned, but a good starting point.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend

- Textastic as code editor (it includes sync features - ftp, webdav... - and a web browser to test your web page)
- jailbreak + openssh
- iSSH for remote but also localhost connection. Provides a nice shell directly on the iPad
- jailbreak + ruby 1.9 from Cydia (not fully working, I would try to build it myself)
- then you create your application on desktop computer, install all gems that you need
- rake gem:freeze (if I remenber well) to embbed all rails dependencies in the app folder
- then put the whole on your iPad and see...

then you are a Rails developer in the wild :-D

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably be best off setting up a little server on your home machine to accept uploads of ruby code, run it on the server and return the results via the browser. I think there are some rails implementations out there that will do this for you.

Comment: any links to those Rails implementations you mention?  thanks!

Comment: Not off the top of my head. Google "running ruby in your browser."

Answer (score 1):

iSSH to your unix server shell, and use "vim" to code and "ruby " to execute. It's no IDE , but it works as long as you have reliable Internet. CCK, Camera Connector Kit, will allow you to use most keyboards, but test first!  Some draw too much power, including Apple's own keyboard!  :-P. Apple wireless keyboard works fine though, and is very portable. ;-)